# How to fix custom page authorization

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I came across the fact that when logging in through an automatically created authorization page, all elements hidden for users without authorization (without a session) immediately appear. But if I set up a custom login page, then in order for hidden elements to appear, I must first refresh the page.

*src/app/signin/page.tsx*

```js
import { SignInForm } from "@/components/SignInForm";
import { Fingerprint } from 'lucide-react';

export default async function Signin() {
  return (
    <div className="stack bg-[#1E1E28] max-w-[600px] w-full h-auto p-4 rounded-[45px] m-auto">
      <div className='flex justify-self-center justify-center items-center'>
            <Fingerprint className='stroke-[#9DFB79] size-8 mr-2' />
            <h2 className='font-inter sm:text-[30px] text-[24px] sm:font-bold font-medium text-left'>Авторизация</h2>
      </div>
      <SignInForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*src/components/SignInForm.tsx*

```js
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import type { FormEventHandler } from "react";

const SignInForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (res && !res.error) {
      router.push("/dashboard");
    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form grid gap-4 mt-6">
      <input className="bg-[#363D4E47] h-10 rounded-full text-center font-inter text-[18px] font-normal" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email" />
      <input className="bg-[#363D4E47] h-10 rounded-full text-center font-inter text-[18px] font-normal" type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Пароль" />
      <button className="text-black hover:text-[#9DFB79] justify-self-center items-center bg-[#9DFB79] p-3 rounded-full w-full text-center font-inter text-lg font-medium hover:bg-[#D779FB]" type="submit">Войти</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export { SignInForm };
```

*src/auth.ts*

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { User } from 'next-auth';
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { users } from '@/data/users';
export const { 
    handlers: { GET, POST }, 
    auth, 
    signIn, 
    signOut 
} = NextAuth({ 
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
              email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "dev@example.com" },
              password: {  label: "Пароль", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
              if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) return null;
      
              const currentUser = users.find(user => user.email === credentials.email,)
      
              if (currentUser && currentUser.password === credentials.password) {
                const { password, ...userWithoutPass } = currentUser;
      
                return userWithoutPass as User;
              }
              return null
        }
          }),
    ],
    pages: {
      signIn: '/signin'
    }
})
```

*SignInForm[Update]*

```js
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useEffect, type FormEventHandler } from "react";

const SignInForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (res && !res.error) {
      router.replace("/dashboard");
    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      router.replace("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [session, status, router]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form grid gap-4 mt-6">
      <input className="bg-[#363D4E47] h-10 rounded-full text-center font-inter text-[18px] font-normal" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email" />
      <input className="bg-[#363D4E47] h-10 rounded-full text-center font-inter text-[18px] font-normal" type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Пароль" />
      <button className="text-black hover:text-[#9DFB79] justify-self-center items-center bg-[#9DFB79] p-3 rounded-full w-full text-center font-inter text-lg font-medium hover:bg-[#D779FB]" type="submit">Войти</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export { SignInForm };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useSession` hook from `next-auth/react` to subscribe to session changes. After the sign-in is successful, call `router.replace(router.asPath)` to refresh the current page or use the `signIn` callback to handle any UI updates.

Here is how you could modify your `SignInForm` :

```js
// src/components/SignInForm.tsx
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react"; // Import useSession
import type { FormEventHandler } from "react";

const SignInForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status } = useSession(); // Use the useSession hook

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (result.ok && !result.error) {
      // Instead of router.push, consider using router.replace to refresh the page.
      // This will refresh the page and ensure that session-dependent UI updates.
      router.replace("/dashboard");
    } else {
      console.log(result.error);
    }
  };

  // If the session changes and we have a user, redirect to the dashboard
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      router.replace("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [session, status, router]);

  // ... (rest of your component)
};

export { SignInForm };
```

Comment: I changed SignInForm as you advised, but unfortunately I still have this problem. Added modified SignInForm to the question - SignInForm[Update]